# gsoapssl Undefined reference error

Tags: ssl, openssl, gsoap

I am trying to user gsoapssl in a web service client and I have been using gsoap with out ssl up to now. I have included gsoap++ ssl crypto and gsoapssl and I also tried including stdsoap2.h in the main class.My issue is I am still getting

```
/home/user/cppworkspace/XXXXXProject/Debug/../API.cpp:494: undefined reference to `soap_ssl_init'
```

Can Some one point me where to check.

I am using eclipse CDT in ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My openssl version is 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.22. You need to install OPENSSL first (or ) and compile all the sources of your application with option **-DWITH_OPENSSL**. If the error still exists, try to add stdsoap2.cpp into your project.